# Importing WiFi settings from Microsoft account

Tags: wi-fi, sync, samsung-galaxy-s-4, windows

I have a bunch of saved WiFi passwords on my Windows 8 laptop that automatically transfer from one PC to another when I log in using my Microsoft account. Does anyone know a way to transfer these saved passwords to my Android device (Samsung Galaxy S4)?  I've tried researching the issue to no avail.

Comment: If you are talking about a password manager like keepass, then you might be able to accomplish this. If so, what password manager are you using? if you mean they are transferred just because they are stored on your windows device, no, you won't be able to transfer them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to view all the saved passwords, but if you are currently connected to a network, you can search "View Network Connections" on your computer, then double click on the network you are connected to. Click wireless properties, and go to the security tab. If you check "Show characters", you can view the password for the network you are connected to.

Comment: Thank you but I am looking for an automatic solution, not a manual one.  I have done extensive research on the topic and have found nothing.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think that's going to work. I suggest keeping a list of important passwords on your phone, and secure the file with a password so no one can open it.